# Behaviour of the apply tactic when the goal and the applied term match

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

Suppose we have `A B C : Prop`.
Given a context with `H : A -> B -> C` and a single goal `A -> B -> C`,
why is it possible to `apply H` to finish the proof, solving the current and only goal?

I thought the `apply` tactic generates a new goal for each of the arguments of the term being applied should its conclusion match (or be unifiable with) the current goal.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing would happen if your goal was only `C`: to prove `C` from `H: A -> B -> C`, you would have to provide witnesses for `A` and `B`. However, your current situation is just an instance of proving `P` knowing `P`, whatever the shape of `P` is. Therefore, by `apply`ing `H`, you provide enough information to close the goal.

Comment: But why `apply H` works? Apply attempts to inspect conclusion of the term being applied (according to the documentation) - but in this case, the conclusion is `C`, not `A -> B -> C`. For example in this scenario, I understand why `assumption` solves the goal - which is saying "I want to prove `P` knowing `P`".

Comment: (I'm not 100% sure about what I'm going to say, I'm a bit rusty of the internals of Coq) `apply` tries to unify the full goal with `H`, not just the last part of the implication. Here the matching is exact so you don't have any trailing subgoals.

Comment: Well of course the full goal is attempted to be unified, I am surprised that also the **entire** term being applied is unified - according to coq docs, "*The tactic apply tries to match the current goal against the conclusion of the type of term.*"

Comment: I don't remember enough to tell you exactly what they mean by "conclusion", but you can consider `H` to be a nullary predicate returning a data of type `A -> B -> C` ;)

Comment: "Conclusion" is just the succedant of the last implication. I understand I can consider it as a nullary predicate, but why would Coq consider it a nullary predicate :)?

Comment: Because Coq tries to do as much as possible to help you, and it's unification algorithm seems to be quite eager to match as much as possible. You might have better luck for a more informative answer on the Coq mailing-list Coq-Club